# Java Properties file. Problems with setProperty() method

Tags: java, properties, properties-file

I try to overwrite existing property value in `Properties` file using `Properties#setProperty()` method.

But I get an extra backslash...

For example I have following entry inside Properties file:

```
#url to server
url=http://192.22.222.222
```

and when I try to overwrite value `http://192.22.222.222` by new value `http://192.33.333.333` I get followong result:
`http\://192.33.333.333`

i.e. first backlash is unnecessary. I

Where is problem?

Comment: If you want to read the properties file by Java again then it wouldn't be a problem like @Jon Skeet mentioned in his answer, but if the file has to be read by other programs then you can remove those backslashes in the file using "sed" (sed 's/\\//g' <filename>) in Linux, I don't know the windows equivalent of sed though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem. When you load the file again, you won't see a backslash in the property value. The escaping code is choosing to escape all colons (and probably all equals signs) regardless of whether it's strictly required. (When they're not part of the key, you don't *have* to escape them, but it probably makes the code simpler to do so.)

So long as you're always loading the code using one of the `Properties.load` methods, you should see no problems at all.

Comment: You still might want to get rid of the extra slash if the file is used by other (non-Java) programs, too.

Comment: @Thomas: I wouldn't use a properties file in other non-Java programs. If I wanted to make it easier to interoperate, I'd use XML.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd probably do something similar. My point was more that there might be a good reason to get rid of the slash - one being if you want to re-use the properties file from outside Java. Then your initial "There's no problem" might no longer hold.

Answer (score 2):

From [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29):

> The key contains all of the characters in the line starting with the
>   first non-white space character and up to, but not including, the
>   first unescaped `'='`, `':'`, or white space character other than a line
>   terminator. All of these key termination characters may be included in
>   the key by escaping them with a preceding backslash character; for
>   example,
>
> `\:\=`
>
> would be the two-character key `":="`.

Answer (score 1):

Java properties will escape some characters like colon when writing a property value.
See [Properties#store](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29).

This is considered a feature because the Properties format allows colons as key/value separators (see the source of Properties#load method)